# .NET/C# - Disposing an object with the 'using' statement

Tags: c#, .net, using-statement

Suppose I have a method like so:

```
public byte[] GetThoseBytes()
{
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        ms.WriteByte(1);
        ms.WriteByte(2);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Would this still dispose the 'ms' object? I'm having doubts, **maybe because something is returned before the statement block is finished.**

Thanks,
AJ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. `using (x = e) { s }` is sugar for `{ x = e; try { s } finally { x.Dispose(); } }`

Comment: And a return inside the body of a try..finally will execute the finally clause before the return actually happens.

Comment: @dthorpe: Umm, yeah. Whoops :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [Using creates a try..finally block](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tinguusingstatement.aspx), so it disposes the ms (and even does a null check in case you set ns to null).

Comment: (Just ignore that nonsense about "The CLR converts your code into MSIL" in that article)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the whole idea behind the Using statement is that it automatically disposes of whatever stream/object you are "using". nicely done.