# What happens if i return before the end of using statement? Will the dispose be called?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, idisposable, using-statement

I've the following code

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     //code
     return 0;
}
```

The `dispose()` method is called at the end of `using` statement braces `}` right? Since I  `return` before the end of the `using` statement, will the `MemoryStream` object be disposed properly? What happens here?

Comment: Aaap... I take that back. I just found a near duplicate, after some very dedicated searching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641692/net-c-disposing-an-object-with-the-using-statement Now, the question is asked entirely differently, but the ultimate question is pretty much the same. I suppose we can consider this a dupe after all.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Yes, `Dispose` will be called. It's called as soon as the execution leaves the scope of the `using` block, regardless of what means it took to leave the block, be it the end of execution of the block, a `return` statement, or an exception.

As @Noldorin correctly points out, using a `using` block in code gets compiled into `try`/`finally`, with `Dispose` being called in the `finally` block. For example the following code:

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     //code
     return 0;
}
```

effectively becomes:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
try
{
    // code
    return 0;
}
finally
{
    ms.Dispose();
}
```

So, because `finally` is guaranteed to execute after the `try` block has finished execution, regardless of its execution path, `Dispose` is guaranteed to be called, no matter what.

For more information, see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

*Addendum:*
Just a little caveat to add: because `Dispose` is guaranteed to be called, it's almost always a good idea to ensure that `Dispose` never throws an exception when you implement `IDisposable`. Unfortunately, there are some classes in the core library that *do* throw in certain circumstances when `Dispose` is called -- I'm looking at you, WCF Service Reference / Client Proxy! -- and when that happens it can be very difficult to track down the original exception if `Dispose` was called during an exception stack unwind, since the original exception gets swallowed in favor of the new exception generated by the `Dispose` call. It can be maddeningly frustrating. Or is that frustratingly maddening? One of the two. Maybe both.

Comment: I think you'll find it's effectively compiled into a try-finally block with a call to `Dispose` in finally, so it's effectively working off the implementation of `finally`, as you describe.

Comment: @Noldorin: exactly. Although I suppose I could be explicit about that. Edit forthcoming....

Comment: Also note that there are some circumstances in which the finally block is not guaranteed to execute, such as using Environment.FailFast and if a StackOverFlowException occurs.

Comment: @C.McAtackney: also a good point. Also, IIRC, OutOfMemoryException; basically if you can't catch the exception because it's a critical execution failure, Dispose won't be called. Of course, in such a case the program is guaranteed to crash, along with any memory allocated to it, so in 99.9% of cases it's a non-issue, unless you're doing wonky stuff like writing to a file in your dispose method. Aside from the catastrophic program crash, that is.

Comment: You should never use the 'using()' statement with WCF - refer to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx) for more info. Here's a snippet I use for WCF proxies:'   WCFProxy variableName = null;
   try
   {
    variableName = new WCFProxy();

    // TODO code here

    variableName.Proxy.Close();
    variableName.Dispose();
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
    if (variableName != null && variableName.Proxy != null)
    {
     variableName.Proxy.Abort();
    }
    throw;
   }
'

Answer (score 19):

`using` statements behave exactly like `try ... finally` blocks, so will always execute on any code exit paths.  However, I believe they are subject to the very few and rare situations in which `finally` blocks are not called.  One example that I can remember is if the foreground thread exits while background threads are active: all threads apart from the GC are paused, meaning `finally` blocks are not run.

**Obvious edit:** they behave the same apart from the logic that lets them handle IDisposable objects, d'oh.

**Bonus content:** they can be stacked (where types differ):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("string"))
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("", conn))
{

}
```

And also comma-delimited (where types are the same):

```
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("", conn), 
       comm2 = new SqlCommand("", conn))
{

}
```

Comment: According to another answer in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/9396151/6142097, for the second example (comma-delimited), the type of the second parameter should not be specified.

Comment: @mihkov Good point, just tried this myself. I didn't back track to previous language versions though so I can't tell if this was always the case, or a minor change with Roslyn.

Answer (score 5):

Your MemoryStream object will be disposed properly, no need to worry about that.

Answer (score 3):

With the `using` statement, the object will be disposed of regardless of the completion path.

Further reading...

- http://aspadvice.com/blogs/name/archive/2008/05/22/Return-Within-a-C_2300_-Using-Statement.aspx
- http://csharpfeeds.com/post/8451/Return_Within_a_Csharp_Using_Statement.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your code in reflector after you compile it.  You'll find that the compiler refactors the code to ensure that dispose is called on the stream.