# c# Disposing of datacontext

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, scope, dispose

3 examples that have the same functionality:

### Method 1

Using uses braces

```
public static int TicketsRequiringSupportResponse()
{
    int ReturnValue = 0;
    using (var dc = new CrystalCommon.MainContext())
    {
        ReturnValue = (dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions.Where(c => c.awaitingSupportResponse == true).Count());
    }
    return ReturnValue;
}
```

### Method 2

Using has no braces

```
public static int TicketsRequiringSupportResponse()
{
    int ReturnValue = 0;
    using (var dc = new CrystalCommon.MainContext())
        ReturnValue = (dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions.Where(c => c.awaitingSupportResponse == true).Count());
    return ReturnValue;
}
```

### Method 3

No braces, and return within the using block

```
public static int TicketsRequiringSupportResponse()
{
    using (var dc = new CrystalCommon.MainContext())
        return (dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions.Where(c => c.awaitingSupportResponse == true).Count());
}
```

Do all of these dispose properly?  Method 3 is neatest, and has the least code, but I'm worried it won't dispose properly, because the return statement will break.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens if i return before the end of using statement? Will the dispose be called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247617/what-happens-if-i-return-before-the-end-of-using-statement-will-the-dispose-be-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they all do the same thing. The braces only add explicit scope; by default the `using` only applies to the next statement. Returning out of a `using` will still dispose (it's essentially a try/finally behind the curtain)  My preference is #3, but with the braces added for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I'd say that Method 1 is neatest IMO - I know the braces are extras, but they help clarify/organize code.  And having your variable declared and returned outside the using block makes for easier real-time debugging.

Answer (score 1):

They all do the same and dispose the context correctly. The first and the second are exactly the same. The first and the second both translate to the following code:

```
int ReturnValue = 0;
Context dc = null;
try
{
    dc = new CrystalCommon.MainContext();
    ReturnValue = (dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions.Where(c => c.awaitingSupportResponse == true).Count());
}
finally
{
    if(dc != null)
        dc.Dispose();
}
return ReturnValue;
```

The third one translates to this:

```
Context dc = null;
try
{
    dc = new CrystalCommon.MainContext();
    return (dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions.Where(c => c.awaitingSupportResponse == true).Count());
}
finally
{
    if(dc != null)
        dc.Dispose();
}
```

Because the finally block is executed when the scope of the try block is left, both codes really are equivalent.

Comment: Doesn't return stop any further code executing though in regards to the third translation?

Comment: The finally clause is executed. From the execution point of view, the second piece of code is executed like the first piece of code.

Comment: @Tom: If `finally` is present, it will _always_ be executed prior to returning scope to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

@Talljoe explains well, they are all equivalent; all I will add is a fourth example, which actually just demonstrates what Talljoe details, but with a slight modification to formatting:

```
public static int TicketsRequiringSupportResponse()
{
    using (var dataContext = new CrystalCommon.MainContext())
    {
        return dataContext .tblHelpCentreQuestions.Where(
            question => question.awaitingSupportResponse == true).Count();
    }
}
```

Note, we add scoping braces for the `using` and further remove redundant parentheses from the return statement, then simply drop a line and indent to allow a better flow for reading, as opposed to a long line (however, *long* is debatable.) I've also tried to give the `DataContext` and lambda argument somewhat descriptive names.