# using statement with multiple variables

Tags: c#, using-statement

Is it possible to make this code a little more compact by somehow declaring the 2 variable inside the same using block?

```cs
using (var sr = new StringReader(content))
{
    using (var xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr))
    {
        obj = XmlSerializer.Deserialize(xtr) as TModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `new XmlTextReader()`. Use `XmlReader.Create()`

Comment: `new XmlTextReader()` has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. By using `XmlReader.Create()`, you will get the best derived `XmlReader` class possible, as opposed to just the one `XmlTextReader` class.

Comment: Come on, it's not like this question was about XmlTextReader specifically! Please stay on topic!

Answer (score 693, accepted):

The accepted way is just to chain the statements:

```
using (var sr = new StringReader(content))
using (var xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr))
{
    obj = XmlSerializer.Deserialize(xtr) as TModel;
}
```

Note that the IDE will also support this indentation, i.e. it intentionally won’t try to indent the second `using` statement.

Comment: Does this use the one-liner-no-braces rule to scope the statements within each other, or actually compile into some sort of chain?

Comment: @peachykeen It is a nested block but I think that in this case this is undistinguishable from a chain due to the semantics of `using` anyway. Or else I don’t understand what you mean by chain: note that in order for `using` to work properly, each resource requires its own `try`…`finally` block.

Comment: I see no difference between this code and the code int the question.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn Yes, exactly. This is intentional – this is the most concise way C# offers: removing the parentheses and omitting the indentation. Notice how the IDE offers *explicit* support for this (otherwise it would indent the second statement).

Comment: @KonradRudolph My question is kind of confusing, but I'm asking if this is actually a discrete language feature designed for multiple `using`s, or just the same as `if (x) if (y) { z; }`. I think your comment answers that, though; I'm reading it as the latter?

Comment: @peachykeen Yes, it’s definitely *not* a discrete language feature, merely nested blocks. The IDE *does* treat it specially for the purpose of indentation though.

Comment: I'd still prefer to nest them.. I prefer indented code. Clearer to me what's being used and disposed.

Comment: I really wish C# had a form of `using` that didn't begin a new block, but instead disposed the variables at the end of the block in which they're declared, something like: `{ using var x = new Reader(); x.Read(); }`

Comment: IL code still remains the same. In all two nested try finally blocks get generated in the IL code. The xtr variable which gets instantiated later gets disposed in the inner finally block and the sr variable which got instantiated before gets disposed in the outer finally block.

Comment: @StefanDragnev C# 8 (VS2019) has [something like that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations).

Answer (score 155):

**The following only works for instances of the same type!** Thanks for the comments.

This sample code is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yh598w02.aspx):

```
using (Font font3 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f), font4 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f))
{
    // Use font3 and font4.
}
```

Comment: This only work when variables are of the same type.

Comment: that only seems to work if both objects are of the same type

Comment: Then declare the variables as IDisposable and cast later?

Comment: @Robert Jørgensgaard Engdahl: Yes, that works too. Just tried it.