# How write several using instructions?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, using

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using statement with multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396064/using-statement-with-multiple-variables)

I have several disposable object to manage. The CA2000 rule ask me to dispose all my object before exiting the scope. I don't like to use the `.Dispose()` method if I can use the using clause. In my specific method I should write many using in using:

```
using (Person person = new Person()) {
    using (Adress address = new Address()) { 
        // my code
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write this on another way like:

```
using (Person person = new Person(); Adress address = new Address())
```

Comment: What you want to use will become very confusion....it also is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can declare two or more objects in a `using` statement (separated by commas).  The downside is that they have to be the same type.

**Legal:**

```
using (Person joe = new Person(), bob = new Person())
```

**Illegal:**

```
using (Person joe = new Person(), Address home = new Address())
```

The best you can do is nest the using statements.

```
using (Person joe = new Person())
using (Address home = new Address())
{
  // snip
}
```

Answer (score 20):

The best you can do is:

```
using (Person person = new Person())
using (Address address = new Address())
{ 
    // my code
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You *could* do

```
using (IDisposable iPerson = new Person(), iAddress = new Address())
{
    Person person = (Person)iPerson;
    Address address = (Address)iAddress;
    //  your code
}
```

but it's hardly an improvement.

Answer (score 6):

You can only use multiple objects in a single using statement if they are of the same type.  You can still nest using statements without brackets.

```
using (Person person = new Person())
using (Address address = new Address())
{

}
```

Here is an example of a multiple object, same type using statement:

```
using (Person p1 = new Person(), p2 = new Person())
{

}
```