# I operate with file descriptors correct, but I still get an error

Tags: c#

```
string fileText;
using (var reader = File.OpenText(pathToSave)) {
    fileText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    reader.Close();
}

using (var stream = File.Open(pathToSave, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
    Byte[] text = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("test1" + Environment.NewLine);
    stream.Write(text, 0, text.Length);

    text = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("test2" + Environment.NewLine);
    stream.Write(text, 0, text.Length);

    stream.Close();
}
```

I don't operate with files anywhere else.

I always close file descriptors after reading / writing, but I still get an error, that the file is used by another process.

What do I do wrong?

The error appears on `FileMode.Append`.

Comment: You need to post the complete error and stack trace.

Comment: Why are you writing to the stream directly? You could just use `File.ReadAllText` and then either use a method like `File.AppendAllText` or keep using `File.Open` but use a `StreamWriter` so you don't have to work with bytes. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file).

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it seems  `fileText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();` locks the file, so you need to complete this task before using this file again.

You can use `ReadToEnd` instead of `ReadToEndAsync` to run synchronously:

```
string fileText;
using (var reader = File.OpenText(pathToSave)) {
    fileText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'll try it. Can I use `using` with reading & writing in the same block scope?

Comment: Did it work? Yes, you can use same `using` as well. But in your case just try my answer, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@John Doe
Replying to your comment, sadly I don't have enough reputation to do it in the comments. Yes of course you can! Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/9396092/13294196 (and also the question in that thread to understand it if you don't)
EDIT: and make sure to see Joelius's advice about using streamreader and streamwriter, it's a much better solution than operating on bytes.