# using statement for disposing connection object in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, dispose, using

I am currently using this approach to dispose off the connection with datacontext object.

```
using (var db = GetDbContext(_connectionString))
{
    List<Procedure_Name> result =
        (from x in db.storedprocedure select x)
            .ToList<Procedure_Name>();
    return result;
}
```

I want to know is this the correct way to dispose of connection object or guide me the best possible approach to be used in this context.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247617/what-happens-if-i-return-before-the-end-of-using-statement-will-the-dispose-be)

Comment: Yes this is the correct way. Just a note here: you can't use *lazy loading* and load the related entity lazily because the db is disposed.