# How to build a JSON based on 3 tables using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to display a JSON using a JsonResult method in MVC, I am using Entity Framework but my issue is that the PostMan is displaying a server error:

The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

I am using a query which involves 3 different tables, however one of those tables might retrieve more that 3 different rows.

This is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult RetreiveResume(int User)
    {
        using (var context = new DexusEntities())
        {
            var collection = (from p in context.CND_PersonalData join
                              pd in context.CND_ProfessionalData on p.UserId equals pd.UserId join
                              ex in context.CND_ExperiencesData on p.UserId equals ex.UserId select p).ToList();
            return Json(collection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using asp mvc core?

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398356/solving-the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed-and-can-no-longer-be-used

Comment: you should include the subcollections of the main entities that your expression returns. like CND_ExperiencesData.Include("collectionName"), it would be easier to help you if you shared your model definition.

Comment: I am not sure. I think I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move return line after using. You are disposing context just after trying to return results. You can check this link for more information: [What happens if i return before the end of using statement? Will the dispose be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247617/what-happens-if-i-return-before-the-end-of-using-statement-will-the-dispose-be)

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult RetreiveResume(int User)
{
    var collection = new CND_PersonalData();

    using (var context = new DexusEntities())
    {
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
        collection = (from p in context.CND_PersonalData join
                          pd in context.CND_ProfessionalData on p.UserId equals pd.UserId join
                          ex in context.CND_ExperiencesData on p.UserId equals ex.UserId select p).ToList();
    }

    return Json(collection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: It says: Cannot convert type System.Collections.Generic.Lis<MySolution.CND_PersonalData> to MySolution.CND_PersonalData

Comment: I changed to List<CND_PersonalData> collection = new List<CND_PersonalData>(); but it's not working.

Comment: You still have same error or different one? And your postman http method is get right?

Comment: Can you also try to disable lazy loading? context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

Comment: Kadir, your last comment worked perfectly!! context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; solved the problem. I had to do a couple of modifications in the code as well.

Comment: Could you please modify your answer to select it as functional? Just copy and past my code and add the context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; before the return.

Answer (score -1):

could you please try to put the return after the brackets like the following :

```
using (var context = new DexusEntities())
        {
            var collection = (from p in context.CND_PersonalData join
                              pd in context.CND_ProfessionalData on p.UserId equals pd.UserId join
                              ex in context.CND_ExperiencesData on p.UserId equals ex.UserId select p).ToList();
            return Json(collection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```